# Checking if a point is on a line in 3 dimensions

Tags: c#, geometry, line, point

This method is supposed to tell you if a point is on the given line or not.  Currently, it works fine as long as no component of the direction vector is 0 (I am using the parametric representation of a line).  With no 0, I should get xResult=yResult=zResult if the point is on the line. If there is a 0 in the direction vector, at least one of those three is 0 and therefore is not equal to all of the others, but the point could still be on the line.

What is the best way to handle the zero case for finding if a point is on the given line?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the passed point is on the line, false otherwise
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="passedPoint"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Boolean IsOnLine(Line passedLine)
    {
        Boolean pointIsOnLine = false;

        //Get components of this point
        Dimension xPoint = new Dimension(DimensionType.Millimeter, X.Millimeters);
        Dimension yPoint = new Dimension(DimensionType.Millimeter, Y.Millimeters);
        Dimension zPoint = new Dimension(DimensionType.Millimeter, Z.Millimeters);

        //Get components of the base point of the line
        Dimension xBasePoint = new Dimension(DimensionType.Millimeter, passedLine.BasePoint.X.Millimeters);
        Dimension yBasePoint = new Dimension(DimensionType.Millimeter, passedLine.BasePoint.Y.Millimeters);
        Dimension zBasePoint = new Dimension(DimensionType.Millimeter, passedLine.BasePoint.Z.Millimeters);

        //Find difference between passed point and the base point
        Dimension xDifference = xPoint - xBasePoint;
        Dimension yDifference = yPoint - yBasePoint;
        Dimension zDifference = zPoint - zBasePoint;

        DimensionGenerator dg = new DimensionGenerator(DimensionType.Millimeter);

        //Instantiate the 3 result variables
        Dimension xResult = dg.MakeDimension(-1);
        Dimension yResult = dg.MakeDimension(-1);
        Dimension zResult = dg.MakeDimension(-1);


        //Solve for the multiplier using each direction and make sure they are all equal.
        //If any component of the direction vector is 0, the result will be zero and should therefore be directly assigned to 0 to avoid dividing by 0
        if(passedLine.XComponentOfDirection.Millimeters == 0)
        {
           xResult = dg.MakeDimension(0);
        }

        if(passedLine.YComponentOfDirection.Millimeters == 0)
        {
            yResult = dg.MakeDimension(0);

        }

        if(passedLine.ZComponentOfDirection.Millimeters == 0)
        {
            zResult = dg.MakeDimension(0);
        }

        else
        {

            xResult = dg.MakeDimension(xDifference.Millimeters / passedLine.XComponentOfDirection.Millimeters);
            yResult = dg.MakeDimension(yDifference.Millimeters / passedLine.YComponentOfDirection.Millimeters);
            zResult = dg.MakeDimension(zDifference.Millimeters / passedLine.ZComponentOfDirection.Millimeters);

        }


        //If the 3 results are equal, the point is on the line. If they are not, the point is not on the line.
        if (xResult == yResult && xResult == zResult)
        {
            pointIsOnLine = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pointIsOnLine = false;
        }

        return pointIsOnLine;
```

Comment: XML documentation and function name contradicts passed parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with inexact numbers, comparing for equality is a bad idea. I'd try the following approach: take the vector from the base point of the line to the point, and take the direction vector of the line. Compute their cross product. If the point lies on the line, the two vectors will be collinear, and their cross product will be the zero vector. So compute the squared length of the vector (to avoid the unneccessary square root) and if that falls below some threshold, your point lies on the line in question.

But if you want to stay closer to your own code, notice that you have three `if` followed by a single `else`. So the else block will still get executed if one of the first to conditions applies. That's probably causing you trouble. Also note that if you do all your computation in millimeters, you might save a lot of code by just dealing in raw numbers instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going about this a different way. Use math. If the angle between any two vectors is 0, the vectors "share a line".

cos(theta) = (U*V)/(|U|*|V|) (dot product).

APPLIED TO YOUR CODE:

```
double inverse = ((xPoint*xBasePoint) + (yPoint*yBasePoint) + (zPoint*zBasePoint))/((sqrt(xPoint^2 +yPoint^2 + zPoint^2) + sqrt(xBasePoint^2 + yBasePoint^2 + zBasePoint^2));

  if(inverse == 1)
      //points are on the same line
   else
      //points are not on the same line or one point is (0,0,0)
```

Also, look at your if else statements when assigning xresult, yresult, and zresult. The way you have it can still end up dividing by zero if the passedLine.Z is not 0 (goes to else statement).

Comment: Using `Math.ArcCos` here isn't necessary, you could just compare inverse to 1.

Comment: Of the two vectors `U` and `V`, one should be the direction of the line (i.e. `XComponentOfDirection` and friends), the other the *difference* between base point and input point. There is however still a problem if one of these is zero, i.e. if the input point equals the base point. That's one of the reason why I'd prefer my solution.

Comment: I agree, your solution is much less prone to problems.